# The Cloud function that returns a batch commit does not wait for that commit to make changes to the database before it completes

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In Cloud Functions, I have defined a function that makes somes updates using a batch that I commit. This commit is the return of the function. This function simply computes the number of likes of every post (likes and posts are two distinct collections in my Firestore database). Since the whole code is short and very simple to understand, I show it below.

The fact to like or unlike a post (to add or remove a like document from the likes collection) is done client-side by the app. 
The fact to compute some statistics (number of likes per post for example) is down server-side in the following Cloud Function. (because if it was client side, it would be hackable, i. e. Bad statistics would be generated and saved + dealing with statistics doesn't  concern the Android app directly and so it should definitely be computed server-side).

**The important thing to note is: `return batch.commit` is the return of this Cloud Function.**

```
exports.sortPostsByUsersPostsLikes = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if(!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
    }

    const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
    const posts = admin_firestore.collection('list_of_users_posts');
    const likes = admin_firestore.collection('likes_of_users_posts');
    const map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes = [];
    likes.get().then(function(likes_docs) {
        likes_docs.forEach(like_doc => {
            if(!(like_doc.data().post in map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes)) {
                map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes[like_doc.data().post] = 0;
            }
            map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes[like_doc.data().post] += 1;
        });       
        return posts.get();

    }).then(function(posts_docs) {
        posts_docs.forEach(post_doc => {
            if(post_doc.id in map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes) {
                        batch.update(post_doc.ref, "number_of_likes", map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes[post_doc.id]);
            } else {
                        batch.update(post_doc.ref, "number_of_likes", 0);
            }
        });     
        return batch.commit();

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("UNABLE TO SORT THE POSTS");
        console.log(error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'An error occurred when trying to sort the posts.');
    });

});
```

In my Android app, when the user, in the list of the posts, likes a post:

1. First, I add a like in the likes collection
2. When the like is successfully added in the likes collection in database, I refresh the list of the posts
3. When the list of the posts is shown (or refreshed), I call the above Cloud Function in order to re-compute the number of likes of the posts (soon, "of the shown posts").
4. When the number of likes of the posts is successfully recomputed, I show the posts (so the number of likes of each shown post would be correct).

## Question

The problem is: at step 4., the number of likes of each shown post is NOT correct (sometimes it is, sometimes it is not). As if the Cloud Function didn't wait the batch commit ends. Is it a normal behavior? Is there any way to force the Cloud Function to wait for the batch's commit's success?

The code I use, in the Android app, to call the above Cloud Function and then, normally if it succeeds, to show the posts (so normally with the good number of likes, but it's not the case in practice) is:

```
        FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
                .getHttpsCallable("sortPostsByUsersPostsLikes")
                .call()
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void then(@NonNull final Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) {
                        if(requireActivity().isDestroyed() || requireActivity().isFinishing()) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Exception e = task.getException();
                            if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                                FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                                if(ffe.getCode() == FirebaseFunctionsException.Code.UNKNOWN) {
                                    miscellaneous.showErrorPopIn(requireActivity(), R.string.error_sortPostsByUsersPostsLikes);
                                }
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        postsDatabaseModel.getListOfPostsOfUser(the_posts_owner).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
```

## Returning the batch commit and adding a `then` doesn't work

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
.then(function(posts_docs) {
        posts_docs.forEach(post_doc => {
            if(post_doc.id in map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes) {
                        batch.update(post_doc.ref, "number_of_likes", map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes[post_doc.id]);
            } else {
                        batch.update(post_doc.ref, "number_of_likes", 0);
            }
        });     
        return batch.commit();

    }).then(function() {
        return true;

    }).catch(function(error) {
```

Comment: For me, real question would be: why did you go over cloud functions to do simple increment, in this case likes, when you could do that from the the app directly on Firestore by using `FieldValue.increment(1)`? Or decrement `FieldValue.increment(-1)`

Comment: The Android app doesn't have to update the likes of all the posts, it must be server-side. BTW I would have no mean to verify that the Android app would be updating the number of likes with the actual number of likes and not with a hacked, wrong, number of likes. So it must defenitely be a cloud function.

Comment: But note that the fact to like or un line, so add or remove a like from the likes collection, is indeed done client side by the Android app.

Comment: Considering the fact that no like can be generated until users actually presses, from the app, like or unlike means that keeping number of likes in filed in document ea. `likes: 50` and in this case you want to keep `ids` of users who like post as well, makes simple calculation locally solvable. Not saying that your approach will not work per se.

But this depends on how you have structured your data in database.

Comment: @Yupi I actually must store the likes in one collection (post ID, post owner, and ID of the user who liked), and then to have a number of likes counter in each post in the collection of posts , counter which must be updated server-side :-) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correctly [chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) the promises returned by the asynchronous methods but your don't return this entire chain. You should do as follows:

```
exports.sortPostsByUsersPostsLikes = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if(!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
    }

    const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
    const posts = admin_firestore.collection('list_of_users_posts');
    const likes = admin_firestore.collection('likes_of_users_posts');
    const map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes = [];


    // SEE THE ADDITION OF RETURN BELOW
    return likes.get().then(function(likes_docs) {
        likes_docs.forEach(like_doc => {
            if(!(like_doc.data().post in map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes)) {
                map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes[like_doc.data().post] = 0;
            }
            map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes[like_doc.data().post] += 1;
        });       
        return posts.get();

    }).then(function(posts_docs) {
        posts_docs.forEach(post_doc => {
            if(post_doc.id in map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes) {
                        batch.update(post_doc.ref, "number_of_likes", map_posts_id_with_number_of_likes[post_doc.id]);
            } else {
                        batch.update(post_doc.ref, "number_of_likes", 0);
            }
        });     
        return batch.commit();

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("UNABLE TO SORT THE POSTS");
        console.log(error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'An error occurred when trying to sort the posts.');
    });
});
```

---

I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) which emphasize how important it is to return a Promise. Without that, the Cloud Function may terminate at anytime before all the asynchronous operatins are completed.

---

#### UPDATE FOLLOWING YOUR COMMENTS

If you want to log the fact that the Cloud Function was successful, you could do as follows:

```
exports.sortPostsByUsersPostsLikes = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if(!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
    }

    //...

    return likes.get().then(function(likes_docs) {
        //...      
        return posts.get();

    }).then(function(posts_docs) {
        //...          
        return batch.commit();

    }).then(function() {
        console.log("SUCCESS")   
        return null;
    })
     .catch(function(error) {
        //...
    });

});
```

Comment: Just another question: if I take into account your answer AND if I return the batch commit AND if I add a `then` returning true just before the catch/just after the batch commit, would it be better? (since i would finally return a boolean instead of a Promise) - I'm going to watch your videos, ty !

Comment: Adding "a then returning true just before the catch/just after the batch commit" will not bring any value. The only reason of adding a `then()` would be to log something when all the work is done, see the update. PS: these are not "my" videos, but official Firebase ones!! :-)